# Where are the logs of jetty server?

Tags: jetty, graphhopper

I installed graphhopper. According to https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/issues/118 I should look into jetty's server logs.

Where are the logs of jetty server?
Is there an exception or stacktrace in them?
Do I need to enable them or are they automatically generated?

System: Debian.

Where are the logs of jetty server?
Is there an exception or stacktrace in them?
Do I need to enable them or are they automatically generated?

System: Debian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logs are printed directly to the console. Your problem is with the port - why not use the default 8989?